# SDL linking error with linux g++

Tags: c++, linux, g++, sdl

[Here is the error I get from my terminal when I try to compile the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFCaz.png)

```
/*This is the init file that controls all the major background processes
will contain major bliting of backgrounds,surfaces, and handle collision
*/
#ifndef_init_H_
    #define _init_H_

#include <SDL>



class init{
    private:
        bool Running;
        SDL_Surface* Surf_Display;
    public:
        init();
        int OnExecute();
    public:
        bool OnInit();
        void OnEvent(SDL_Event* Event);
        void OnLoop();
        void OnRender();
        void OnCleanup();
};
```

here is the code I pretty much copied from sdltutorials.com if you are wondering about it. I used their basic tutorial. I think there might be a linking error with sdl and my OS but not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Two errors listed - you need a space after the first `#ifndef`, and it seems that your compiler couldn't find the SDL header file(s) - maybe they're not installed, or you need a -Ipath/to/SDL/include compiler option so it looks in the right place.

Comment: I fixed the first error so thank you on that and I am sorry I am kind of new to SDL and g++ so I don't know how to do the path to the SDL folder.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll probably want to ensure that you SDL installed to begin with.  I'm not going to waste your time walking through all that distribution specific stuff.  I'm going to assume you know what you're doing.  After you fix the typos, you could potentially use pkg-config.  It's invoked on the command-lind by typing:

```
$ g++ source.cpp -o program `pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl`
```

** Note the use of ` instead of '. Of course, the -o flags and all that jazz I'm sure you're familiar with.  pkg-config adds the appropriate flags to the command line so that you don't have to worry about manually listing all the necessary command-line arguments.  Of course, the availability of all the *.pc files will vary by distribution, but using Ubuntu 12.04, the above command works. In my experience, pkg-config is appropriately tuned to work on your system no matter what distribution. If you'd like to see what's actually going on under the hood, simply type:

```
$ pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl
```

Comment: I have SDL installed my problem is getting it be seen by g++